# Display content customized by member type?

Tags: ee2, members, content

How do you display content by member type?

Comment: Oh hey, me again. :) Please review the [do not ask guidelines](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which include open-ended, polling-type questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use EE's built-in [Member Groups](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/member_groups.html), then use conditional checking in your templates:

```
{if logged_in_group_id == "5"}
    // Place some group-specific code here
{/if}

{if logged_in_group_id == "8"}
    // Place some group-specific code here
{/if}
```

Comment: Perfect. Was hoping I didn't need an addon.